# Chamar um ArrayList de um JFrame para outro

Tags: java, jframe, arraylist

Preciso chamar um `ArrayList` criado em um `JFrame` para outro `JFrame`. No caso, o usuário faria um registro em um dos JFrames, chamado Cadastro, e a partir disto criaria o objeto Usuario, com login e senha e este objeto será alocado em uma ArrayList. A partir disto, o usuário vai para a área de login e coloca seu login e senha, em outro JFrame, chamado login.

Nesse novo JFrame, o programa precisa conferir se o login e a senha batem com algum dos logins e senhas dos objetos criados pelo registrar, que estão alocados na ArrayList. Por isso preciso da ArrayList criada no arquivo "Cadastro" no arquivo "Login".

O código abaixo, no primeiro JFrame.

```
ArrayList<Usuario> lista = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<Usuario> getLista() {
    return lista;
}

public void setLista(ArrayList<Usuario> lista) {
    this.lista = lista;
}
```

No código abaixo, no segundo JFrame, onde preciso deste ArrayList.

```
    Usuario p;
    List novalista = new Cadastro().getLista();
    p = (Usuario) novalista.get(i);
```

Para chamar os arquivos JFrame, utilizo a ação de apertar o botão.

```
          Cadastro frame = new Cadastro(); 
          frame.setVisible(true); 
          this.dispose();
```

No arquivo Login (onde preciso fazer as validações) já tentei puxar de várias formas, mas nenhuma funciona.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30438/discussion-on-question-by-lucas-cosas-chamar-um-arraylist-de-um-jframe-para-outr)

Comment: Bom, pra começar uma conversa num chat preciso ter X pontos de reputação, por isso a discussão longa..

Comment: A mensagem em meu nome acima é gerada automaticamente após eu mover os comentários para o chat, mas ainda assim ela não pede para vocês terem longas discussões no chat, diz para evitar discussões longas, em qualquer lugar, e as que estavam aqui foram movidas para o chat. O ideal na verdade é que todas as informações necessárias para entenderem corretamente a sua dúvida estejam presentes no corpo da pergunta e não no chat ou nos comentários.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na chamada do seu 2º frame, passe como parâmetro o array de usuários que você já tem.

```
 Cadastro frame = new Cadastro(getLista()); //a lista do 1º frame
 frame.setVisible(true); 
 this.dispose();
```

e dai para utilizar a lista no segundo frame, algo semelhante a isso

```
private List<Usuario> usuario;
public Cadastro(List<Usuario> usuario){

         //inicia os componentes
         // ....

        //utiliza o seu parametro
        this.usuario = usuario;

         //segue a logica
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ajudou bastante, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Já tive a mesma duvida quando fiz projeto de Chat com Socket em Java.
Caso tenha mais duvidas, estou a disposição ...